# Conflict with firebase 11.8.0 and google-services plugin 3.1.2

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-play-services, gradle-plugin

I have an apparent conflict with firebase 11.8.0 and google-services plugin 3.1.2.  The build fails recommending that I use version 11.4.2 of firebase instead.

Relevant extracts of my gradle build files:

Root `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
        ...
    }
}
```

app `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
repositories {
    google()
    ....
}
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0"
    ....
}
```

I've correctly generated the firebase app files:

```
./app/src/debug/google-services.json
./app/src/release/google-services.json
```

When I build with `./gradlew clean assembleDebug`, the build fails with this error:

```
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED
Found com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0, but version 11.4.2 is needed for the google-services plugin.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.4.2.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is to move this line to the **bottom** of the app `build.gradle` file (it shouldn't be at the top):

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is specified in the documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

> Then, in your module Gradle file (usually the app/build.gradle), add
>   the apply plugin line at the bottom of the file to enable the Gradle
>   plugin:
>
> ```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>
> android {
>   // ...
> }
>
> dependencies {
>   // ...
>   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
>
>   // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
>   // added the Google maven respository to your root build.gradle
> }
>
> // ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
> ```